# Pdo Begintransaction rollback failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

My problem is begintransaction rollback not working 

User table

- id  int(11) AI
- balance double(10)
- password  varchar(100)
- eposta  varchar(60)
- lastlogin text()Json

  Siparisler table
- sipid int(11) AI
- packid  int(11)
- userid int(11)
- amount  double(10)
- limit int(6)
- sipcode varchar(15)

DB CONNECT CLASS

```
class baglan
{
    public $vt;
    function db()
    {
        if($this->vt)
        {
            return $this->vt;
        }
        else{
            try
            {
                $this->vt=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=twitterapp;charset=utf8","root","");

            }
            catch(PDOEXception $i)
            {
                die("veritaibanı Bağlantısı yapılamadı Hata Detayı : ".$i->getMessage());
            }
            return $this->vt;
        }
    }
}
```

PAYMENT Method

```
function payment()
{
    $this->db()->beginTransaction();
    try{
        $sipekle=$this->db()->prepare("insert into siparisler set packid=:pack,userid=:alici,limit=:siplimit,amount=:price,sipcode=:code");
        $sipekle->execute(array("pack"=>1,"alici"=>1,"siplimit"=>100,"price"=>10,"code"=>"12ASX43AZ12QP"));
        $bakiye=$this->db()->prepare("update user set balance=balance-:cost where id=:uid");
        $bakiye->execute(array("cost"=>1,"uid"=>1));
        $this->db()->commit();
        return(array("durum"=>"İşlem başarılı"));
    }
    catch(PDOEXCeption $i)
    {
        $this->db()->rollback();

        return(array("hata"=>"İşlem sırasında hata oluştu.Lütfen tekrar deneyin.Sürekli olarak bu hatayı alıyorsanız destek talebi açın:<br>Hata Kodu: ERR-SIP-0_".time()));            
    }       
}
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [hata] => İşlem sırasında hata oluştu.Lütfen tekrar deneyin.Sürekli olarak bu hatayı alıyorsanız destek talebi açın:
Hata Kodu: ERR-SIP-0_1550070987
)
```

siparisler table added data 
user balance not update 
Rollback(); not working
 The user  balance update fails, Siparisler table adding the order is successful. Begintransaction Rollback() method not undo this action

Comment: No is  it necesary PDO ?

Comment: Why did the update fail? You should print `$e->getMessage()` in the `catch` block to see the reason.

Comment: It's not an error if nothing gets updated because `WHERE id = :uid` doesn't find a match. You won't get a rollback in that case.

Comment: @Barmar See, that's what I thought ages ago, then saw a question + answer on here that contradicted that assumption... but I must be mis-remembering the question.

Comment: $this->db()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);
   $this->db()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);<br>
added payment() method

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say with that comment. What was the PDO error that was thrown?

Comment: Begintransaction rollback not working not undo this action

Comment: What engine are you using on those tables? MyIsam or InnoDB? As far as I know, MyIsam doesn't support transactions.

Comment: I using mysql  5.7.21

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for support. Problem resolved. Table convert myisam to innodb. Begintransaction Action success